# Unity 'the object of type has been destroyed' error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm destroying an object in my game in that method :

```
public override void triggerAction(GameObject cube)
{
    base.triggerAction(cube);

    if (cube.GetComponent<Cube>().type == type) {
        DestroyObject(cube);
    }
}
```

and I got an 
`'The object of type 'Cube' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.'` error pointing on this method (the first line) :

```
if (Physics.Raycast(gameObject.transform.position, rayDir, out hit, 1f) && (hit.collider.gameObject.layer == layerMask)) {
        ActionObject obj = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<ActionObject>();
        obj.triggerAction(gameObject);
}
```

This method is called in an 'Update' loop.

I saw on the net that we have to test if the gameobject is not null, but when I test it, I got the same error on the condition :

```
if (gameObject != null) { ... }
```

Thanks for your answers !

EDIT : Here is how I instantiate my object =

```
public GameObject cube; // I put my prefab in the inspector 
...
GameObject newCube = Instantiate(cube) as GameObject;
```

Comment: if (GetComponent<GameObject>() != null) { ... } i am not sure but try.

Comment: When I write it, the raycasting condition isn't working.

Comment: There is no error, but it doesn't pass through the if condition

Comment: I think it is another question to be solved. Need more detail to solve. Edit your question with more details.

Comment: I have no problem to print 'gameobject' which returns the name of the object. I just edited the question with how I instantiate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem, it was a delegate method that was on my object, I just deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure, but since this method is called in `Update`, it is possible that you are trying to destroy the same object (actually, component) twice.

The `RayCast` call only takes colliders in account, so when you delete the `Cube` component from `cube` object, unless `Cube` is the collider, in the next frame, the same object can still be the target of the `RayCast`. But this time, the object won't have any `Cube` component on it and you will get the `'The object of type 'Cube' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.'` error.

To resolve it, you might want to check whether the objects `Cube` component is null or not, not itself:

```
if (gameObject.GetComponent<Cube>() != null) { ... }
```

Comment: I tested it and I got the same problem on the line you wrote.